# Add values to array using for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know this is a simple issue, but I am stumped.

I want to do this using a for loop in JavaScript

```
      var arr = [
        { val: '1', text: '1' },
        { val: '2', text: '2' },
        { val: '3', text: '3' },
       .........
        { val: '30', text: '30' },
        { val: '31', text: '31' }
       ];
```

I tried this. I want create a select list which shows all month day

```
    var arr = [
        for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
             { val: i, text: i },
        }
    ];
```

This shows error.

Comment: did you search anything about it ?

Comment: He has tried something. It did not work. So i think its a valid question

Comment: to be fair, this is a valid line of python: `arr = [{ "val": i, "text": i } for i in range(32)]` and would produce the same result as above

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Javascript does not have list comprehensions like that, try this instead:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    arr.push({ val: i, text: i });        
}
```